# Periodic Cross-Correlation vs Aperiodic Cross-Correlation

Tags: correlation

I am doing research in spread spectrum communication, and many papers frequently use the terms Periodic Cross-Correlation and Aperiodic Cross-Correlation. However, I cannot find a clear definition of these terms and their differences between them.

Also, what is the definition of Odd Cross-Correlation?

Could one share their thoughts on that and maybe share some books/papers?